# How to speed up a set-interval process in the middle and back to slow at end

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the below example code. How can I add some sugar to this function an a a way to start and end smooth but speed up (for example with speed of 100 instead of 100 in the middle of process?

For example from:

```
90  -> 120  = speed 1000 
120 -> 240  = speed 100
240 -> 270  = speed 1000
```

```js
let i = 90;
setInterval(function() {
  if (i < 180) {
    i++;
    console.log(i)
  }

}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` instead. By creating an external function `counterFn` you can call `setTimeout` within it and thus modify the `speed` at which `counterFn` is called:

```js
let i = 90;
function counterFn() {
  let speed = 1000;
  if(i > 120 && i <= 240) { // change speed if i is between range
    speed = 100;
  }

  console.log(i);
  i++;
  
  setTimeout(counterFn, speed); // call counterFn again after `speed` m/s
}

counterFn();
```

**Note**: If you need precise timesteps you may want to consider using [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead.

Comment: This is the right approach, but it should include a caveat about `requestAnimationFrame` as a better alternative for `setTimeout` especially regarding animations - setTimeout/setInterval is not a guaranteed time to execution - it's a minimal time to execution. And it will more-likely-than-not create frame skips or forced renders. Just sayan :)